# How is "In we go" syntactically valid?

Tags: historical-linguistics, grammar, idiomaticity

Various simple sentences occur in English that I can't explain precisely.

"In we went!"
"Off he goes!"

Is this an arcane idiom from an earlier grammar, or is there a general rule that can be abstracted here?

Edit: initially I thought "in" was a preposition but I realise now this is a behaviour of particles.

"Up he looked"
Although for transitive verbs this seems to not work:
*"Up he picked"

It seems that the particle may move to the immediate left of the subject but no further, for example:

*Up, Mary saw John eat

Additionally it isn't possible to substitute it for a normal VP:

*Mary saw up John eat.

Has this been investigated further?

Comment: I think this question is good; it is asking about a systematic property of grammar (the topicalisation of particles).

Comment: "I realise now this is a behaviour of particles" ... I'm not sure. Consider a phrase like "Up the stairs we go" or "Today we will take a look at ...". These are cases of adverbial fronting.

Comment: "In we went" and "off he goes" make perfect sense, but what on Earth does "Up, Mary saw John eat" mean?

Comment: @Tim Foster. Clearly what it doesn't mean is equivalent to "Mary saw John eat up". By moving 'up' beyond the subject the entire sentence falls apart, which is why I prefixed it with *

Comment: @Wilson I think you have exactly defined what I was trying to understand, the adverbial fronting in your examples seem to translate directly over to mine, assuming I was seeing adverbs as particles in these cases due to the severe ambiguity. As someone with a keen interest in linguistics, but no formal training and still a relative beginner, this is exactly the sort of correction that I and many other users could benefit from. Should I have perhaps used a `beginner` tag to forwarn potential answerers that my musings could be way off?

Comment: At the time I had my Advanced English course (as a foreign language) this type of construct was presented to us by our teachers as an "emphatic inversion".  Googling for this term might bring more info (I haven't tried yet).

Comment: FYI - *Up, John ate is also not good. It's well documented that the construction only works when the 'literal' meaning of the particle is used (i.e. *up* can only refer to the direction). I'll write a full answer if I find time.